# How to do POST request that requires dynamic variable in Next.js by Server Side Rendering?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, next.js, use-context

I'm using Next.js framework and made a simple web application.

Using Firebase Auth, I tried to manage only authenticiated users to send requests. So basically, I need that user's id token. But as you know as `user.getIdToken()` doesn't work because `user` could be null. So I had to write `user?.getIdToken()`.

As this result is Promise, I tried to use `useContext` hook. And I could get access to id token from all page files.

But here's the question.

Although I could get id token, as I need to get this inside the Component, it renders by Client Side Rendering. And I could see some delays.... and I want it to be rendered on Server Side. Could you guys help me with this? As I cannot use this **id token** inside `getStaticProps()` or other methods...

Here's my code:

```
export default function Boards() {
    const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000/myproj/asia-northeast3/api";
    const { idToken } = useContext(UserContext);
    const [boardCategory, setBoardCategory] = useState("free");
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        try {
            if (idToken != "") {
                const res = axios.get(
                    BASE_URL + "/post/get", {
                        headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${idToken}`, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
                        params: { "boardCategory": `${boardCategory}` }
                    })
                    .then((response) => {
                        setPosts(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data)));
                    });
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }, [idToken, boardCategory]);
}
```

And this renders on Client Side Rendering so I see some delays...

Thank you guys in advance !

Comment: You can't do it on the server if you're generating your pages at build-time with `getStaticProps`. If you want authentication done on the server-side you'd need to move to `getServerSideProps`. I'd recommend you have a read through [Next.js Authentication](https://nextjs.org/docs/authentication).

Comment: @juliomalves Thank you so much! So they recommend using sessions(`next-iron-session`)! I would try that right away! Thank you so much again!